# is there any proof that metric learning cannot achieve better on image classification task than accepted models (resnet etc)?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, classification

Everything is in the title.

Metric learning seems to be closer to our way of thinking than the best performing models (supervised learning CNNs-based models like resnet or efficientnet). I was looking for research papers that would have try a metric learning-based model for classic classification task on the Imagenet dataset benchmark but I could not find it. That is why I am asking the question here.